# Counting number of 2D points with both coordinates higher than given point in O(logn)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a set of 2D points (x1, y1)...(xn, yn) and one point from that same set (xi, yi), I need to return the number of points such that their x coordinate is bigger than xi and y coordinate is bigger than yi.

Approach is limited to usage of basic data structures such as Array, List (incl. Linked), Stack, Queue, Trees (Binary, BST, AVL, B-tree), Hash Table and Heap.

Required time complexity is O(logn) and you can assume the data is given to you in a data structure of your choice (from the ones provided above), however you wish it sorted and is not counted towards the time complexity.

Because the requirement is O(logn), I thought about having the x-coordinates sorted in an Array and using Binary Search. Though I'm not sure how to have the y-coordinates stored in a way that will preserve the time complexity.

I could most certainly use any hint at resolving this.

Comment: You can have the the y-coordinates stored *for each x-coordinate* (so you have n arrays of n elements each) and precompute the answer for each of the n^2 elements. Query time is still O(log n). It is hard to tell whether this is allowed though.

Comment: @n.m. That would be a bit problematic, because if I still store the y-coordinates of points that their x-coordinate is smaller than x, then I might count them as well.

Comment: Let's try again. There are O(n^2) essentially different queries (draw all the horizontal and all the vertical lines, there are O(n^2) rectangles, the answer is the same for every point inside each rectangle). You store *precomputed answers* for each rectangle in a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem in O(logn) time is to use a binary search tree. We can insert the points into the tree, sorted by their x coordinate similar to your suggestion (except using a BST struct) and then do a binary search for the point (xi, yi).

EDIT:
I'm coding what I had in mind and @n.m. is right. The initial idea won't work. Here's the code. I think in best case it's O(log n) but worst case O(n).

For each node in the tree / sorted array by x value, we can check:

1. If both x and y coords are greater than xi,yi: Increment count and repeat the search for both child nodes.
2. If x is less than xi and y is > yi: search right child because everything to the left of the current node will have an x less than xi.
3. If x > xi and y < yi: search both left and right nodes

   ```
   def countPointsInBST(points, xi, yi):
           return helper(points, xi, yi, 0, len(points) - 1)
   ```

   def helper(points, xi, yi, low, high):
   if low > high:
   return 0
   mid = (low + high) // 2
   if points[mid][0] > xi and points[mid][1] > yi:
   return 1 + helper(points, xi, yi, low, mid - 1) + helper(points, xi, yi, mid + 1, high)
   elif points[mid][0] < xi:
   return helper(points, xi, yi, mid + 1, high)
   elif points[mid][1] < yi:
   return helper(points, xi, yi, low, mid - 1) + helper(points, xi, yi, mid + 1, high)

**Now for another idea:**
What if we do the BST sorted by X value. Find all the nodes that are greater than the given xi. Then create another tree or sort that in O(nlogn) time by Y value, then search for all nodes greater than the given yi. This will be O(logn) + O(nlogn) + O(logn)

Comment: If you meant that every array contains only the y-coordinates of the (i+1)th point and above where xi < x(i+1) for every i, then that should work just fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: It is not clear how this should work. Suppose there are 7 points (1,1), (2,-2), (3,3), (4,-4), (5,5), (6,-6), (7,7) in a perfectly balanced BST (so the root is (4,4) etc).The point we are searching is (0,0). What are the comparisons your algorithm will make?

Comment: @n.m. You are correct. I've rechecked the algorithm and it will ignore all the right ancestors which are potentially higher.

Comment: Yea you're right. That doesn't work. I edited my answer with some code for what I had in mind and another idea that might also work